# How can I refer to another react component?

Tags: reactjs

is there a way to get component's state name,  from another component?

I have a component Chat:

```
import ChatMessage  from './ChatMessage'
class Chat extends Component {
    state = {
        name: 'Bob',
        messages: [],
    }

    getStateName = function(){
        return this.state.name
    }
}
```

and another component ChatMessage:

```
import Chat from './Chat'
class ChatMessage extends Component{
    render(){
            return(
                <p> {Chat.getStateName} </p> 
            )
    }
}
```

I would like to get as a result 'Bob'.
I was thinking of using a function called getStateName,  but it doesn't seem to work. Any idea's how I can fix that?

Comment: Ca you show how you are integrating the `ChatMessage` and  `Chat` together?

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally state is **private** and fully controlled by the component. [Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/) is a library that can be used to manage application wide states via an application store. Refer to redux's [getting started](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts#state-management) to set your app up.

Answer (score 0):

You are on right track to use Components, but you need some changes to look into

here is Stackblitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pnuxzv?file=src%2FChatMessage.js) for your project

your Chat.js component file will be

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Chat extends Component {
  state = {
    name: 'Bob',
    messages: []
  };

  render() {
    return <p>{this.state.name}</p>;
  }
}

export default Chat;
```

And ChatMessage.js component will be

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Chat from './Chat';
class ChatMessage extends Component {
  render() {
    return <Chat />;
  }
}

export default ChatMessage;
```

Comment: @dzuulie let me know if you need any further explanation for how to use components in other components, I hope the above simple solution will let you understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses a plain ES6 class to store user data, and delegates rendering to a React component.

Either create an instance of the class before accessing it:

```js
class User {
  state = {
    name: "Bob",
    messages: [
      "Could you get cucumber from the grocery store?",
      "Don't forget the tomatoes, too!",
      "Scrap the tomatoes. No tomatoes.",
      "Honey, let's get take away instead."
    ]
  };
}

const user1 = new User(); // ← initialising the object instance

const App = () => (
  <>
    <h1> {user1.state.name} </h1>
    <ul>
      {user1.state.messages.map((message) => (
        <li key={message}>{message}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  </>
);

export default App;
```

Or make the state static, which allows you to access it without initialisation:

```js
class User {
  static state = { // ← the state object is now static
    name: "Bob",
    messages: [
      "Could you get cucumber from the grocery store?",
      "Don't forget the tomatoes, too!",
      "Scrap the tomatoes. No tomatoes.",
      "Honey, let's get take away instead."
    ]
  };
}

// no need for initialisation
// const user1 = new User();

const App = () => (
  <>
    <h1> {User.state.name} </h1>
    <ul>
      {User.state.messages.map((message) => (
        <li key={message}>{message}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  </>
);

export default App;
```